# Filtering collection to get items whose properties occured n times in Java 8 using streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Assume that I have a Collection of Person(name, age) objects:

```
Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();
people.add(new Person("Peter", 26));
people.add(new Person("Dane", 24));
people.add(new Person("Gregory", 26));
people.add(new Person("Daniel", 27));
people.add(new Person("Micheal", 27));
people.add(new Person("David", 26));
people.add(new Person("Kate", 21));

people.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.getName()));
```

now I would like to check if there are three guys who have the same age or, if there are pairs of people with the same name, and get these people in another list. So I wrote following generic static method:

```
private static <T> Collection<T> filterWhenMultipleOccurance(Collection<T> collection,
        Function<T, ?> comparisonCriteria, int demandedOccuranceAmount) {
    return collection.stream()
            .filter(item -> collection.stream()
                    .filter(otherItem -> 
                    comparisonCriteria.apply(otherItem) == comparisonCriteria.apply(item))
            .toArray().length == demandedOccuranceAmount)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Now I can call this method to meet my demands:

```
Collection<Person> selectedPeople = filterWhenMultipleOccurance(people, p -> p.getAge(), 3);
System.out.println("---------------");
selectedPeople.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getName()));
```

Which gets me proper list consisting of Peter, Gregory and David.

Somehow I feel this solution is neither elegant nor efficient, since I'm nesting stream().filter call, so I assume that time complexity would be at least O(n^2). Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you specifically expecting a streams solution to be more efficient than a non-streams solution?  I would think simply hashing all entries using the function, and then looking at hash counts would be the most efficient.  No streams (but it would use a Function).

Comment: I assume that java runs some optimization behind the scenes, not triggering certain operations until terminating method is called. Perhaps that is not the case in my solution, but I'm not sure if one can always write a function that would run faster than proper stream combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd better of using the `groupingBy` collector, classifying your elements by the function you give as parameter. This will give you a `Map<Object, List<T>>`.

From there get the stream from the entry set again. Since you're not interested in the keys, you map each entry to its value (a `List<T>`) and filter the lists which have an appropriate size. Finally, you collect the elements into a list again (after flatmapping the lists), resulting in a `List<T>`.

```
private static <T> Collection<T> filterWhenMultipleOccurance(Collection<T> collection,
                                                             Function<T, ?> comparisonCriteria, 
                                                             int demandedOccuranceAmount) {
    return collection.stream()
                     .collect(groupingBy(comparisonCriteria))
                     .values()
                     .stream()
                     .filter(l -> l.size() >= demandedOccuranceAmount)
                     .flatMap(List::stream)
                     .collect(toList());
}
```

In your original solution for each item in the stream, you're filtering all elements of the collections again. So basically you're doing unnecessary operations, because once you filtered an item that satisfies the requirement, you know that every item with the same property given the comparison function will yield the same result.

Also you're using `==` in `comparisonCriteria.apply(otherItem) == comparisonCriteria.apply(item)` which might not work since you're comparing references (I guess this is not what you want).

Finally you are wasting memory because you create an array just for calling `.length`. You can use `count()` directly in this case.

Comment: Well, this is syntactially what I expected, thanks a lot! I will probably do run some benchmarks to see how much I earned thanks to this.

Comment: @PiotrNapadłek I think there might be a balance between the value of `demandedOccuranceAmount` and your input. If it's high with a comparison function giving spread values (or even worse; an injective function), you might create a lot of unnecessary entries in the map. But yes, benchmarking will give you an idea (note that you can also use parallel streams).

Comment: OK, your solution seems to work excellent, with roughly 20000 items in a collection it still runs in couple of millis.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to group the entries into buckets with your given bucketing criteria and then return the list which satisfies your requirement. Something along the lines of:

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();
        people.add(new Person("Peter", 26));
        people.add(new Person("Dane", 24));
        people.add(new Person("Gregory", 26));
        people.add(new Person("Daniel", 27));
        people.add(new Person("Micheal", 27));
        people.add(new Person("David", 26));
        people.add(new Person("Kate", 21));
        Collection<Person> lst = filterWhenMultipleOccurance(people, Person::getAge, 3);
        System.out.println(lst);
    }

    public static <T, X> Collection<T> filterWhenMultipleOccurance(Collection<T> collection,
            Function<T, X> comparisonCriteria, int demandedOccuranceAmount) {
        Map<X, List<T>> grps = collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(comparisonCriteria));
        for(List<T> lst : grps.values()) {
            if(lst.size() >= demandedOccuranceAmount) {
                return lst;
            }
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Not really jazzy or compact but does the job.